# How to make the pop to stay after clicking on Register or Login button in the Popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is this [link](http://wekancode.com/gh/) I am working on. So, I can't able to create `jsfiddle` as it is the huge template.

The problem is in the top right section (Login).

I can click on the **Login** and the the pop-up window appears which shows "Login" and "Register".

But if I click on the "Register" tab, then the entire pop-up window disappears.

How can I fix it?

Here is the related **html**

```
<i class="dropdown profile-dropdown">
<a id="expandMenus" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<span class="hidden-xs">
<i class="fa fa-user"></i>
Login</span> <b class="caret"></b>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="bag fa fa-star">0</i>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" style="min-width: 300px">   

<!-- Login starts-->
<div class="col-lg-12" style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
<div class="main-boxallau clearfixallau" style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
<div class="tabs-wrapper profile-tabs" style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="background-color:#EFEFEF">
<li class="active" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;width:47%;padding:-2px 10px 10px 24px;margin: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">
<a data-toggle="tab" id="showLoginArea" style="color:black;border: 2;
border-bottom: 2px solid #43882C;border-right: 1px solid #43882C;outline: 0;height: 36px;">
<b style="margin:0px 0px 0px 18px">LOGIN</b></a></li>
<li class="" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;width:40%">
<a data-toggle="tab" style="color:black;height:36px;" id="showRegisterArea"><b style="margin:0px 0px 0px 13px">REGISTER</b></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="loginArea">
<div id="login-box-innerallau" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;margin-top: -6%;">
<form role="form" action="http://cube.adbee.technology/index.html">
<div class="input-group">

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email Id" style="border:none;background-color:#EFEFEF;

border-bottom:1px;width:135%;
border: 0;

border-bottom: 1px solid #D0C8C8
outline: 0;
">
</div>
<div class="input-group">

<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;width:135%;
border: 0;

border-bottom: 1px solid #D0C8C8
outline: 0;
">
</div>

<br>
<div id="remember-me-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div class="checkbox-nice">
<input type="checkbox" id="remember-me">
<label for="remember-me" style="font-size:11px;margin:0px 0px 0px -6px !important">
Keep me logged in
</label>

</div>
</div>
<a href="forgot-password.html" id="login-forget-link" class="col-xs-6" style="font-size:12px" ;margin:-2px="" 0px="" -20px="">
Forgot Password
</a>

</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
<br>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="registerArea" style="display:none">
<div id="login-box-innerallau" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;margin-top: -6%;">
<form role="form" action="http://cube.adbee.technology/index.html">
<div class="input-group">

<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email Id" style="border:none;background-color:#EFEFEF;

border-bottom:1px;width:135%;
border: 0;

border-bottom: 1px solid #D0C8C8
outline: 0;
">
</div>
<div class="input-group">

<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;width:135%;
border: 0;

border-bottom: 1px solid #D0C8C8
outline: 0;
">
</div>
<div class="input-group">

<input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" style="background-color:#EFEFEF;width:135%;
border: 0;

border-bottom: 1px solid #D0C8C8
outline: 0;
">
</div>
<div id="remember-me-wrapper">
<div class="row">
<a href="forgot-password.html" id="login-forget-link" class="col-xs-6" style="font-size:12px" ;margin:-2px="" 0px="" -20px="">
Forgot Password
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-xs-12">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 btn-facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> facebook
</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12 btn-twitter">
<i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Login ends -->

</ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you provide your javascript code since this is probably a js issue ?

Comment: Hi, the javascript i use is custom.js .. can u pls do view source..

Answer (score 3):

Replace  `line 4: of custom.js 
$(".dropdown").toggleClass("open");`

with

`$("#expandMenus").toggleClass("open");`

You are toggling the whole menu on every click of the class `.dropdown`

Login and register have the class `dropdown`

Comment: Hi,thanks, i have updated.. but still i have that error....

Comment: should i remove `data-toggle="dropdown"` from  `<a id="expandMenus" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">`

Comment: @BizDevB no.  Update the site and let me know when that's done.

Comment: Hi can u refresh this page twice .. i have updated just now ... http://wekancode.com/gh/public/asset/custom.js

Comment: Sir, r u there.. i have updated it....

Comment: @BizDevB yeah give me a sec.

Comment: Thanks.. if you have teamviewer. you can see and edit my code directly sir..

Comment: @BizDevB try and create a jsfiddle with the same problem and I will be able to help better.  No teamviewer.  Goodluck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101831/discussion-between-biz-dev-b-and-norcalknockout).